# dplyr summarize date by weekdays

Tags: r, dplyr

I have multiple observations from different persons on different dates, e.g.

```
df <- data.frame(id= c(rep(1,5), rep(2,8), rep(3,7)),
                 dates = seq.Date(as.Date("2015-01-01"), by="month", length=20))
```

Here we have 3 people (id), with different amount of observations each.

I now want to count the mondays, tuesdays etc for each person.

This should be done using `dplyr` and `summarize` because my real data set has many more columns which I summarize with different statistics.

It should be some something like this:

```
summa <- df %>% group_by(id) %>%
           summarize(mondays = #numberof mondays,
                     tuesdays = #number of tuesdays,
                       .........)
```

How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the lubridate package:

```
library(lubridate)

summa <- df %>% group_by(id) %>%
    summarize(mondays = sum(wday(dates) == 2),
    ....
```

Answer (score 4):

I would do the following:

```
summa <- count(df, id, day = weekdays(dates))

# or:
#    summa <- df %>% 
#      mutate(day = weekdays(dates)) %>% 
#      count(id, day)

head(summa)
#Source: local data frame [6 x 3]
#Groups: id [2]
#
#     id        day     n
#  (dbl)      (chr) (int)
#1     1 Donnerstag     1
#2     1    Freitag     1
#3     1   Mittwoch     1
#4     1    Sonntag     2
#5     2   Dienstag     2
#6     2 Donnerstag     1
```

But you can also reshape to wide format:

```
library(tidyr)
spread(summa, day, n, fill=0)
#Source: local data frame [3 x 8]
#Groups: id [3]
#
#     id Dienstag Donnerstag Freitag Mittwoch Montag Samstag Sonntag
#  (dbl)    (dbl)      (dbl)   (dbl)    (dbl)  (dbl)   (dbl)   (dbl)
#1     1        0          1       1        1      0       0       2
#2     2        2          1       1        1      1       1       1
#3     3        1          0       2        1      2       0       1
```

My results are in German, but yours would be in your own language of course. The column names are German weekdays.

---

If you want to use `summarize` explicitly you can achieve the same as above using:

```
summa <- df %>% 
  group_by(id, day = weekdays(dates)) %>% 
  summarize(n = n())  # or do something with summarise_each() for many columns
```

Answer (score 1):

Base Date functions:

```
summa <- df %>% group_by(id) %>%
    summarise(monday = sum(weekdays(dates) == "Monday"),
              tuesday = sum(weekdays(dates) == "Tuesday"))
```